# Set battery threshold in Lenovo Legion Y540 having Ubuntu

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery

How can I set battery threshold in Ubuntu 20.04 installed on **Legion Y540**. There is a conservation mode for this purpose in windows. Also there is no such option in the BIOS (and i have latest available BIOS version as I updated it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. Since I have dual-booted with windows, I choose the conservation mode setting from there and that setting retains for Ubuntu. Note: there is no option for this in the BIOS (maybe future update of BIOS will provide it)